# subprocess.run() doesn't return the expected output

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a shell script in python but i don't get the expected result

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
cat $file1 $file2
```

python:

```
print(sp.run(/path/script.sh + " text1.txt text2.txt", shell=True, check=True, text=True, capture_output=True))
```

if I run the script on the terminal the results are correct, I join the two files.
But if I run the python code it seems to do nothing.

Comment: `/path/script.sh` is not a valid Python literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet should work for you:

```
import subprocess as sp

file_name = "path/to/script.sh"
file1 = "path/to/file1"
file2 = "path/to/file2"

output = sp.run([file_name, file1, file2], check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
print(output.stdout)
```